# Would a Catalan secession from Spain spark whole new borders in Europe?

Tags: european-union, catalonia, spain, exit-polls

If the Catalan government decides to call for independence later today, would the EU have to recognize Catalonia as an independent country? The U.K. can't veto this decision because of Brexit, and no other big powerhouses in the EU have an outstanding region with a wish for independence, so no EU nation would get involved in Catalan interlacings. Would the EU have the option not to recognize a country formed/developed within the EU borders or would all maps have to be remade?

Secondly if Catalan secession happens would Basque country also cry for independence? The Spanish government would look weak. The ideal time for secession would be just after the Cataxit.

Comment: What countries have regions with a separatist movement is answerable.  How the Catalan issue will affect them?  Not so much.  Perhaps a Catalan secession will prevent future secession, as the countries will take their separatist movements more seriously.  We don't know and won't know.

Comment: Actually both Spain and Belgium said they would veto Scotland in the EU. In theory the recognition could be immediate since EU directives and regulations are already being followed in the regions. In practice I would expect resistance from a couple of countries. Personally I think both would end up being accepted but the process would likely take a bit more than ideal.

Comment: @armatita in your personal view, would a EU with smaller countries be a more united EU?

Comment: I don't think the size of the countries is necessarily an important factor for the unity of the EU. Self-determination is a recognized right by international law. And, as I said, in practice these regions are already EU. The biggest issue here is "why"? Is Catalonia independence a break from irreconcilable issues with the Spanish government, or just the latest symptom of the rise of nationalism word wide? This last hypothesis concerns me greatly if true. Is the secession of Catalonia for humane reasons, or for a flag?

Comment: I think the first question you have to ask is "Does the EU as a body recognise countries, and if so how?" The answer is: not as such. [*Member states* recognise countries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Kosovo#Positions_taken_by_intergovernmental_organisations). See the situation with Kosovo for precedent as to how things work out when some but not all EU countries recognise a UDI.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Catalonia declares independence (today, as you said) then Spain will stop it and apply direct governance there, ignoring the declaration and the Catalan government. They will do so because the EU will not recognize Catalonia and will support Spain to avoid it. Catalonia will not have the power to do it or they can enter into a conflict (but that is almost impossible, nobody wants it)

See my answer in this question: [What could Spain do legally if Cataluña proclaims independence?](https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/what-could-spain-do-legally-if-catalu%C3%B1a-proclaims-independence/25185#25185)

EU has the opinion and will not recognize it, and therefore Catalonia will not be so willing to declare independence in a situation like this. Catalonia wants to split but with more or less good terms. EU will not change anything, but if some day they really split from Spain on 'good terms' then there will be more regions that will also complain. One of them being Basque Country, that as you said will push in this moment to Spain to also secede.

Example: http://www.reuters.com/article/us-spain-politics-catalonia-eu/eu-urges-spain-to-talk-to-catalans-condemns-violence-idUSKCN1C712P?il=0

> The Commission statement also supported Madrid’s line that the vote, which Catalan leaders said recorded a huge result for independence, was “not legal” under Spain’s constitution.

http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/862293/catalonia-referendum-independence-european-union-eu

> A spokeswoman for the Socialists and Democrats Party said the Spanish constitution needed to be recognised and respected.
>   She said: “The European Parliament as representative of all European people is calling all parties to sit down and work together for a peaceful and responsible solution, in the framework of the Spanish constitution.”
>   **It is just the latest warning issued by europhiles in a bid to first block, and then ignore the referendum**

They do not find legal the referendum and therefore a declaration of independence

About the veto, Spain is still part of one of the nations voting and any government in Europe wants any region to split. It is not true that any EU country does not have a region with these feelings. Germany has Bavaria, now is not so strong the independence feeling, but after a 'Cataxit' this feeling will increase, and Germany wants to avoid this.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bavarian_nationalism

http://www.express.co.uk/news/world/863323/Catalonia-referendum-independence-Catalan-Spain-regions-Europe-separatist-movement

> Too many countries in the European Union have secessionist problems, including the UK, Belgium and Italy and this is not a unique problem
>   Willem Buiter, chief economist at Citi

Comment: very nice answer. However I have an additional question: 
How is it within the principals of democracy to restrict a region to a country? Should a region not be able to vote out of a country forcing the country to respond to the demands of its regions?

Comment: If we talk about straight democracy, then the bases of it in Spain makes it ilegal. If it is fair or not is another topic for another longer question-answer. That can be longer discussed, for example: if catalonia is able to do it, me and my family in my house will be able to do it and then apply whatever legality I want in my house no? It is all based in dialogue, willingness and at the end money. Money is the one that decides everything. If you want, you can ask another question about it, but do not make it too broad or think about ask it in law exchange

Comment: In addition to this answer keep in mind that Catalans in a vast majority recognize the benefits of being part of the EU and while they may not feel Spanish at all times they definitely want to remain European Union's citizens. A departure from Spain means a defacto leave from the EU along with Spain's veto power(as mentioned above)  means that at least at first and for the foreseeable future if Catalonia wont be a member of the EU.